# Errors concerning depreciated eregi

Tags: php

This is the error i am receiving

```
Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/socia125/public_html/profile.php on                  
line231
```

This is my code

```
// Loop through the array of user agents and matching operating systems
   foreach($OSList as $CurrOS=>$Match) {
    // Find a match
    if (eregi($Match, $agent)) {
            break;
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Help == [reading the documentation](http://php.net/eregi)

Comment: It's just a warning, but you should consider replacing POSIX regex by PCRE regex: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php

Comment: i found a fix unsure if its safe using // Loop through the array of user agents and matching operating systems
   foreach($OSList as $CurrOS=>$Match) {
    // Find a match
    if (!stristr($Match, $agent)) {
            break;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match` instead of `eregi`.

But it seems like all it does is searching for a string, so you might be able to use `stripos` instead.

```
// Loop through the array of user agents and matching operating systems
   foreach($OSList as $CurrOS=>$Match) {
    // Find a match
    if (stripos($Match, $agent) !== FALSE ) {
            break;
```

I can't guarantee that it works as it should, since we don't see all of the code (especially contents and example values of `$Match` and `$agent`)

Answer (score 2):

Well, [as the manual quotes](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php),

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this
>   feature is highly discouraged.

Use [`preg_match()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead. Be a bit careful though, because you cannot convert your search pattern 1:1 from [`eregi`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) to [`preg_match()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Example to show the difference:

```
$t = "this is a test...";
if (preg_match("/test/i", $t)) echo "match!";
if (eregi('test', $t)) echo "match!";
```

There is a [whole chapter](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) in the php manual dedicated to the PCRE syntax.

But if you're just simply trying to find a string, use something like [`strstr`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) or [`stristr`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php), those are faster and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

eregi() is deprecated as of 5.3.
You may ignore this as it is just a warning.

I would recommend to use preg_match() instead.

See the link [here](http://www.devthought.com/2009/06/09/fix-ereg-is-deprecated-errors-in-php-53/)